# How to force https on Google Cloud AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, go, https, tls1.2

I am trying to force https for all traffic to an app hosted on Google Cloud AppEngine. https works, but despite following the instructions for rewriting http traffic to https, it's still possible to access the site with http, which causes problems.

I have added this to the app.yaml:

```
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: _go_app
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
```

but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

I am using the julienschmidt router and then this to handle all routes:

```
log.Fatal(fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)))
```

I have looked at using http.ListenAndServeTLS but this takes extra parameters and I can't work out what the values of those should be in the Google AppEngine context.

```
log.Fatal(fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":8443", "cert.pem", "key.pem", router)))
```

Where are "cert.pem" and "key.pem"?

I've read that I don't need to explicitly serve TLS in my app, because AppEngine will handle it for me, so even if I knew what the parameters were, I'm not sure it would help in *forcing* https.

http://sapling.appspot.com
https://sapling.appspot.com
http://sapling.money
https://sapling.money

All of the above work, but I don't seem able to force either of the http versions to https.

Comment: Thank you. That may well help but I still don't know what the values of the parameters in http.ListenAndServeTLS() should be. ie if I am using the SSL certificates of Google App engine, where are they?? What is the path?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the `secure:always` handler and the requests are not being automatically redirected, then you are probably using App Engine Flex?

App Engine Flex does not support handlers, you can see this in the Flexible [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml) documentation.

Instead, you can check in your code if a request was sent via HTTP or HTTPs and redirect. This is done with the [App Engine specific header](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/request-headers#app_engine-specific_headers) `X-Forwarded-Proto`.

The implementation is configured on your end and there is a brief [paragraph](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#https_and_forwarding_proxies) on the subject.

You can also view similar Stack posts with the same answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48752601/how-to-enforce-https-traffic-to-google-app-engine-with-custom-domain/48755788#48755788)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct for including the `secure: always` element in your [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_secure) as this will force HTTPS for your app's handlers.

However, I believe the following App Engine Documentation for "Securing Your App" found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/application-security#https_requests) may be of some use to you. As indicated in that link, you can convert HTTP URLs to HTTPS by simply replacing the periods between each resource with a `-dot-` instead. You may see the example provided below.

```
   http://[SERVICE_ID].[MY_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com
   https://[SERVICE_ID]-dot-[MY_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com
```

For additional information about HTTPS URLs and resource targeting you may see how requests are routed [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-requests-are-routed).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I am not using any subdomains or service IDs so I don't see how that will help, unless I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Strict-Transport-Security header to instruct the browser to prefer https over http for a given page or an entire domain as outlined in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-requests-are-handled#forcing_https_connections). In order to add [HTTP Strict-Transport-Security headers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#hsts) (HSTS) to your app, you must implement the headers within your app's code, not within your app's config file (app.yaml or appengine-web.xml).

It is also a good idea to enable HSTS preloading if you register your application with Google's HSTS [preload list](https://hstspreload.org/). Firefox and Chrome will never load your site over a non-secure connection.

Comment: are you using app engine standard or flex, which go version?